# Keyerror with list comprehension using 3 lists when using IMDB API

Tags: python

I am creating a little project showing movie scores from movies my friend and i have watched together over the years. For that i am using API Dojo's IMDB's API from RapidAPI.
I am starting with importing an excel sheet, which has the correct columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

kolonner = ['ID' , 'ÅR' , 'TITEL' , 'RATING_AMBY' , 'RATING_MATTIS' , 'SAMLET_RATING' , 'STUDIE' , 'INSTRUKTØR' , 'GENRE' , 'RUNTIME']
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Downloads\FilmlisteNY.xlsx' , header = 0 , index_col=0 , sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Then i have made a function that appends rows to that sheet, based on 3 inputs, the movie ID from IMDB, and each of our scores, the function is as follows :

```
#Definerer funktion

def FilmData(film , RATING_AMBY , RATING_MATTIS):
#SKRIV ID og Score PÅ FILM OG KØR CELLE



    #HENTER FØRSTE RUNDE OPLYSNINGER BASERET PÅ ID
    url = "https://imdb8.p.rapidapi.com/title/get-meta-data"

    querystring = {"ids":film}

    headers = {
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "Can't show you key, but it is here",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "imdb8.p.rapidapi.com"
    }

    response = requests.request("GET" , url , headers=headers , params=querystring)
    response = response.json()


    # Henter informationer omkring DIRECTOR

    url2 = "https://imdb8.p.rapidapi.com/title/get-full-credits"

    querystring2 = {"tconst":film}

    response2 = requests.request("GET" , url2 , headers=headers , params=querystring2)
    response2 = response2.json()

    #GEMMER INFORMATIONER I GLOBALE VARIABLE
    global ID 
    ID = film
    global ÅR
    ÅR = response[film]['title']['year'] #if response[film]['title']['year'] in response else None 
    global TITEL
    TITEL = response[film]['title']['title'] #if response[film]['title']['title'] in response else None 
    global GENRE
    GENRE = response[film]['genres'][0] #if response[film]['genres'][0] in response else None 
    global RUNTIME
    RUNTIME = response[film]['title']['runningTimeInMinutes'] #if response[film]['title']['runningTimeInMinutes'] in response else None 
    global INSTRUKTØR
    INSTRUKTØR = response2['crew']['director'][0]['name'] #if response2['crew']['director'][0]['name'] in response else None 
    global RATING_SAMLET
    RATING_SAMLET = (RATING_AMBY + RATING_MATTIS) / 2
    list = [ID , ÅR , TITEL , RATING_AMBY , RATING_MATTIS , RATING_SAMLET , 0 , INSTRUKTØR , GENRE , RUNTIME]
    global df
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([list] , columns = kolonner) , ignore_index = True)
```

I had another sheet before where everything was filled out manually, but i want to use my function on the previous films, so i made 3 lists with movie ID's and scores which are the following :

```
listamby = [4,  5,  4,  3,  4,  5,  3,  3,  3,  2,  1,  3,  3,  4,  4,  3,  2,  4,  1,  5,  5,  3,  5,  5,  4,  3,  4,  5,  1,  1,  4,  4,  3,  4,  4,  1,  5,  5,  2,  2,  5,  5,  4,  1,  4,  4,  3,  3,  2,  4,  4,  4,  3,  2,  3,  2,  4,  1,  2,  2,  3,  4,  1,  1,  3,  4,  1,  3,  1,  3]
listmattis = [3,    5,  4,  3,  4,  5,  2,  3,  4,  2,  1,  2,  2,  4,  2,  2,  3,  4,  1,  5,  5,  3,  4,  5,  4,  4,  4,  3,  3,  1,  4,  4,  4,  5,  4,  3,  5,  4,  2,  1,  5,  5,  3,  1,  4,  5,  4,  4,  2,  4,  3,  4,  3,  2,  4,  2,  4,  1,  3,  2,  4,  4,  2,  1,  3,  4,  2,  3,  1,  3]
IDS = ["tt2105044","tt0407887","tt7784604","tt0012299","tt0070224","tt10126662","tt1259521","tt0123755","tt2321549","tt0758742","tt5059406",    "tt4733640",    "tt4163224",    "tt0078767",    "tt0112735",    "tt3654796",    "tt4399952",    "tt0386846",    "tt7043012",    "tt1375666",    "tt0117381",    "tt0079643",    "tt1677733",    "tt0211130",    "tt0443706",    "tt0004832",    "tt0104800",    "tt0098374",    "tt0395584",    "tt0440803",    "tt0464141",    "tt3958034",    "tt0014199",    "tt0816692",    "tt0101674",    "tt1703199",    "tt0059043",    "tt0215632",    "tt1320244",    "tt0805570",    "tt0182313",    "tt0327056",    "tt0065387",    "tt1662293",    "tt1442053",    "tt0309698",    "tt0333952",    "tt0335106",    "tt21336716",   "tt7349950",    "tt2386278",    "tt0430359",    "tt0103181",    "tt0069345",    "tt1119191",    "tt2450186",    "tt0057664",    "tt0147630",    "tt1285009",    "tt7153766",    "tt2388715",    "tt0324114",    "tt0816556",    "tt0007574",    "tt0361862",    "tt5430018",    "tt0424404",    "tt0486822",    "tt0370848",    "tt6114050"]


[FilmData.get(x,y,z,0) for x,y,z in zip(IDS,listamby,listmattis)]
```

However i get a keyerror after the 5th entry where it says Keyerror : year.
I tried to look use the inputs manually in RapidAPI and then everything is as expected.

Can it be because of a maximum number of calls per second or something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the use of all these global variables, what is `FilmData.get`, pass `df` as argument to the function, don't call your variable `list`, what is the 4th arg `0`, `FilmData.get(x,y,z,0)`, function has 3 arguments

Comment: Right.  `FilmData` is a function.  It does not have a `get` method.

Comment: most likely it is in the line `response[film]['title']['year']`, why don't you post the TraceBack of the exception, use a debugger to see what each variable is and why you have a key error, we are not going to debug your program/Homework

Comment: It was a bit confusing, because i tried different things to fix. The original code was without .get() and the 4th argument in the function, so the list comprehension if actually : [FilmData(x,y,z) for x,y,z in zip(IDS,listamby,listmattis)]

Comment: I think it is because of the request limit. There is a limit of 5 pr. second. Will answer the question if it works. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

The API had a hard limit of 5 requests pr. second, therefore i needed to implement a sleep timer into my function.

```
time.sleep(1)
```